# AWS S3 Event JSON parsing for simple email via SNS

Tags: json, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an event notification when a file is uploaded to an S3 bucket which sends an email to an SNS Topic with only me receiving it.

How would I use the jq command line app, or some other AWS function or service like Lambda to parse the JSON data sent from an S3 bucket to SNS to make it simpler?

e.g.

From this...

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
      "eventTime": "2017-02-22T09:16:03.964Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:XXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "123.456.789"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "XXXXXXXXX",
        "x-amz-id-2": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "Backup Successful",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "my.bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "backup_2017-02-22-0915_Test_Web_Site_1c709c59af2a-others.zip",
          "size": 493812,
          "eTag": "zxbmcnbskdezb",
          "sequencer": "y238623rqwde"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To this...

```
backup_2017-02-22-0915_Test_Web_Site_1c709c59af2a-others.zip
```

I just cannot get my head around the syntax and how to use Lambda or something else for this email content!

I am happy to use another AWS option instead of SNS if that's easier for my requirements.

File > S3 Bucket > Notification > Lambda > SNS Email

or

File > S3 Bucket > Notification > Lambda Email

I am a relative newbie at this, so need some decent examples please.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What language are you developing in?

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS Lambda (assuming you would use Python for the Lambda runtime), you can parse the event like this:

```
def my_handler(event, context):
  records = event['Records']
  s3_records = filter(lambda record: record['eventSource'] == 'aws:s3', records)
  object_created_records = filter(lambda record: record['eventName'].startswith('ObjectCreated'), s3_records)
  for record in object_created_records:
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']
    # key will be "backup_2017-02-22-0915_Test_Web_Site_1c709c59af2a-others.zip" in your case
    # now you can use boto3 to act on the key
```

Once you have extracted the `key`, you can either use `boto3`'s [SNS `publish`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) method to send a notification to your SNS topic, or you can send an email directly to yourself using (again `boto3`) [SES `send_email`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email).

Here's [a nice tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) from AWS that will help you wire your S3 bucket to your Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks. When I try that, I receive the following error (sorry real newbie):-   "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"

Comment: Yes you must rename the function my_handler to lamba_handler

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting output: null